# Trouble with setting the 'left' property using jquery's .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to get a 'paddle' to move using the left and right arrow keys. The values change properly whenever I press the left or right keys, and the string seems to be correct, but after the .css() runs, it just returns with the original value. Please help?
-- Code used for debugging marked with // --

````
var paddx = 0;
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var ballx = 0;
var bally = 0;
var maxw = window.innerWidth;
var maxh = window.innerHeight;
$(document).keydown(function(keyPressed){
    paddle = document.getElementById('paddle');
    var temppaddx = window.getComputedStyle(paddle).getPropertyValue('left');
    paddx = parseInt(temppaddx, 10);
    console.log(temppaddx +" "+ paddx);//
    if (keyPressed.keyCode == 37){
        paddx -= 1;
        if (paddx < 5){
            paddx = 5;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed.keyCode == 39){
        paddx += 1;
        if (paddx > maxw - 130){
            paddx = maxw - 130;
        }
    }
    temppaddx = paddx.toString(10) + 'px';
    console.log(temppaddx +" "+ paddx);//
    $('paddle').css('left',temppaddx);
    temppaddx = window.getComputedStyle(paddle).getPropertyValue('left');//
    console.log(temppaddx +" "+ paddx);//
});```
````

Comment: `$('paddle')` looks like a typo, unless your html does indeed have a `<paddle>` element in it?

Comment: Is the element absolutely positioned?

Comment: I have a <div> with the id paddle

Comment: `#paddle` is the correct id selector

Comment: @Taplar That seems to have done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementById('paddle')` but also `$('paddle')`.

It should be `$('#paddle')` to make jQuery's selector find the correct element.